# DecimalFormat - no decimal separator

Tags: java, double, decimalformat

I use the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format numbers to strings, and vice-versa.

In my database, Java doubles are represented in a specific way : for example 128.88 is stored "00012888". To achieve that, I use the "00000.00" pattern and remove the "." decimal separator after formatting, which is not a smart solution.

Is there a way to tell DecimalFormat not to use any decimal separator ? Can I make it understand where is the integer part and the fraction part in a string representing a decimal number ?

I would prefer not having to multiply, divide, truncate or make roundings before conversions.
Is there a magic pattern for this ? Or the DecimalFormat class is not as flexible ?

I precise I can't use the String.format() method because I work on a Java 1.4 platform.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you change the database column to `DECIMALS(9, 2)`? Would still be stored without point, and be more normal. Furthermore BigDecimal is very awkward but a better solution than double. You could make a view with the correct column definition, and simply getDouble or getBigDecimal.

Comment: no, unfortunatly. But BigDecimal seems to be a quite good solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`DecimalFormat` is not mighty enough to do that.

You could use a method like this:

```
double getD(String fixedWidthNumber) {
    return Double.valueOf(fixedWidthNumber.substring(0,6)+"."+fixedWidthNumber.substring(6,8));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("234.33");
DecimalFormat decFrm = new DecimalFormat("000.00");
char decSep = decFrm.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
String resultStr = decFrm.format(value).replace(Character.toString(decSep), "");
```

result: 3423433

Answer (score 0):

There is not an efficient solution, since DecimalFormat requires a primitive char as a decimal separator.

A workaround is to set the decimal separator to an uncommon character and then replace it with an empty String

```
DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('X');

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
return decimalFormat.format(value).replace("X", "");
```

It's not great, but it does it's job